# NSPredicate for NSDictionary with NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Given Image has structure of data

[image]

I am  able to get the data from the FirstText and LastText and NSPredicate was `subData.FirstText contains[cd] %@ OR subData.LastText contains[cd] %@` but I am not able to get filter data from MiddleText inner dictionary (English,Hebrew,Trans).Please let me know what should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the items by extending your key path:

```
subData.MiddleText.English contains[cd] %@
```

Comment: it's crashing and saying "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x25e4844> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key English.'" any idea?

Comment: i have same structure as an array.